# How many Number of Networks for class B and class C?

Tags: networking, ip

In the tutorial on ip4 adress classes:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ipv4/ipv4_address_classes.htm

Class B has 16384 `(2**14)` Network addresses and 65534 `(2**16-2)` Host addresses.
Class C gives 2097152 `(2**21)`Network addresses and 254 `(2**8-2)` Host addresses.
[image]

In the tutorial on ip4 adress classes:
`http://www.vlsm-calc.net/ipclasses.php`

Class B has `163842(2**14-2)`Network addresses and 65534 `(2**16-2)` Host addresses.

Class C gives 20971520`(2**21-2)` Network addresses and 254 `(2**8-2)` Host addresses.
[image]
Both of them for class A ,the number of networks is 126 `(2**7 – 2)`.
Which number of networks on class B and class C is correct?
For class B , the number of networks  is    `(2**14-2)`  or `(2**14)`?
For class C , the number of networks  is    `(2**21-2)`  or `(2**21)`?

Comment: What is exactly what you want to know? That tutorial you added is not very good...

Comment: Classful networks are obsoleted long time ago. Why do you need them? Now internet works with classless networks and use CIDR routing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Comment: @DmitryPoroh is correct; classful networking has been dead for over 20 years (in 1993) probably longer than you have been alive, killed by VLSM and CIDR. See RFCs 1518 and 1519. Please, let it rest in peace. Also, you do not subtract 2 from the number of networks. The RFCs are clear that all zeros and all ones networks are perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than point to a reference, I'm going to enumerate them all, and then use mathematics:

1. Class A addresses go from `0.X.X.X` to `127.X.X.X` - a total of (127-0+1)=128 networks.

   [Note that `127.X.X.X` is reserved as the LocalHost network - most assume that means only `127.0.0.1`, but it's actually all of them.]

   - With the `.X.X.X`, each network cannot use `.0.0.0` or `.255.255.255`, so that's the `-2` in the Host count.
2. Class B addresses go from `128.0.X.X` to `191.255.X.X` - a total of (191-128+1) * (255-0+1) = 16,384 networks.

   - With the `.X.X`, each network cannot use `.0.0` or `.255.255`, so that's the `-2` in the Host count.
3. Class C addresses go from `192.0.0.X` to `223.255.255.X` - a total of (223-192+1) * (255-0+1) * (255-0+1) = 2,097,152 networks.

   - With the `.X`, each network cannot use `.0` or `.255`, so that's the `-2` in the Host count.

In short, neither source is correct if they both say that there are 126 Class A networks.

As a final example: in the old "Classful" networks neither `0.0.0.0` nor `0.255.255.255` is a valid Host address, but any of `0.0.0.1`, `0.0.0.255`, `0.0.1.0` and `0.255.255.254` are.

[If you want a source, how about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network#Introduction_of_address_classes]

Answer (score 1):

- For class B , the number of networks is `[(2^14)-2]`, and the number of hosts is `[(2^16)-2]`
- For class C , the number of networks is `[(2^21)-2]`, and the number of hosts is `[(2^8)-2]`

The "-2" is because the first address for each range is reserved for identify localhost or local network address (*.0), and the last one is the broadcast address (*.255).

I.e: for a private C network, the range of addesses is:

```
192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.255
```

I can not use first and last, so the range is now:

`192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254` `-->` There is a range of 254 addresses, which is exactly `[(2^8)-2]`

If you want to learn more about networking and subnetting you can take a look at this CISCO doc: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13788-3.pdf

Comment: Maybe this tutorial helps you too: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/dynamic-address-allocation-resolution/13711-40.html?referring_site=bodynav

Comment: You do not subtract 2 from the number of networks. The RFCs are clear that all zeros and all ones networks are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: You are correct that you subtract two from the number of hosts, for the reason you state. But you don't subtract two from the number of networks.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network#Introduction_of_address_classes)

> The blocks numerically at the start and end of classes A, B and C were
> originally reserved for special addressing or future features, i.e.,
> 0.0.0.0/8 and 127.0.0.0/8 are reserved in former class A; 128.0.0.0/16 and 191.255.0.0/16 were reserved in former class B but are now
> available for assignment; 192.0.0.0/24 and 223.255.255.0/24 are
> reserved in former class C. While the 127.0.0.0/8 network is a Class A
> network, it is designated for loopback and cannot be assigned to a
> network.[5]

Inference:
Class A : 2^N - 2
Class B : 2^N
Class C : 2^N - 2